# Example of spin chains with finite-lifetime quasi-particles?

Tags: condensed-matter, spin-models, quasiparticles, spin-chains

Does anyone know a one-dimensional spin model where the low-energy excitations have a finite lifetime? (E.g. in terms of the spectral function $\mathcal S(k, \omega)$ this means one would get a finite width in $\omega$-space)